# Files in ram (tmpfs) representing a single-producer multi-consumer buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, tmpfs

> **constraints:** My system has 250MB RAM memory available. The amount of
>   data generated by the producer lies around 5Mb/sec. I need to provide
>   a buffer of around 30 seconds. So around 150MB...

> **What I'm trying to achieve:** Implement a single-producer single-consumer
>   ringbuffer in a tmpfs mount. One thread should work as a producer filling the buffer and multiple threads should fetch data from the buffer.

So far I've tried `vectors` (c++) all leading to an allocation error. It seems using contiguous memory allocation won't work (for amounts around 50 MB). Using `deque` (non contiguous) on the other hand works fine. But I'm limited to the kernel response regarding memory management and the available memory could lie below the expected amount to initialize the buffer... That's why I would rather use `tmpfs` as it is mounted with a predefined size.

Using a class containing a circular buffer with relevant concurrently-safe methods and properties (possibly lock-free?), I could create the buffer using a sequence of files in `tmpfs` with a duration of 1 second/each.

Would this be fast enough compared with the deque implementation or would I feel the lag caused by accessing the files concurrently from multiple threads?

*What are your thoughts guys...Am I missing something?...*

Comment: which boost version?

Comment: Boost version 1.60

Comment: https://github.com/ned14/boost-lite/blob/master/include/ringbuffer_log.hpp looks like it will solve your problem. It's threadsafe and uses whatever storage you tell it e.g. a memory mapped section. Just feed the `ringbuffer_log` class a custom policy for the type you are storing.